# v.in.wfs by GRASS in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, wfs

I was trying to include the v.in.wfs tool in my processing modeler however whenever I run the model this tool gives me an error.

While trying to connect the same link through layer--> add layer --> add WFS layer it works[image]

WFS link I'm using: http://202.159.223.250/erdas-apollo/vector/INDIASTATES

[image]

Comment: Something looks a little odd in the GetCapabilities response, but not sure if this is causing your problem (HTTP but also port 443 ~ HTTPS). What if you use: https://nsdiindia.gov.in/erdas-apollo/vector/INDIASTATES? as the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this GetCapabilities request: http://202.159.223.250/erdas-apollo/vector/INDIASTATES?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0

Based on the results, the following parameters:

*GetFeature URL:* `https://nsdiindia.gov.in:443/erdas-apollo/vector/INDIASTATES?`

*Alternate spatial reference system:* `EPSG:4326` (I don't see it passed in the algorithm execution)

*Comma separated names of the layers:* `STATE`

*GRASS GIS region (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):* `68.12381744384766, 97.4078369140625, 6.762208461761475, 37.08933258069704`

[image: v.in.wfs]

Returned 22052 features, so wait for the download. I would recommend to save the output to a folder instead of the temporary file.

I'm not sure if it is all right with the data. Maybe I remove some features accidentally...

After *Delete duplicate geometries*: 11181.

[image: map]

Comment: It works perfectly after following the steps you've mentioned above. Now I can continue with my research project. Thanks a ton!

Comment: When I try to run the following http://202.159.223.250/erdas-apollo/vector/INDIADISTRICTS?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities in v.in.wfs it is again giving an error even when I did exactly the same thing as you did

GetFeature URL: https://nsdiindia.gov.in:443/erdas-apollo/vector/INDIADISTRICTS?

Alternate spatial reference system: EPSG:4326 

Comma separated names of the layers: DISTRICT

GRASS GIS region (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax): 68.12381744384766, 97.4078369140625, 6.762208461761475, 37.08933258025636

@Gabriel

Comment: @VaibhavGupta, Most welcome! The GetCapabilities request, do it in a web explorer, returns a XML page with the capabilities of the WFS server. https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

Comment: I got the xml page and then tried to execute the v.in.wfs but somehow it is working only for the states layer and not the districts one

Comment: I see, the GetFeature URL parameter seems to be `http://nsdiindia.gov.in:443/erdas-apollo/vector/INDIADISTRICTS?` instead of `https`. May be the server is not well configurated?

Comment: It works when I use https instead of http 
Thanks for all the help and replies to my specific queries